# function not working when key value is assigned directly from dictionary to a variable python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary

So I have been learning python for I guess 10 days or so and I came across some weird behavior by python.

Code snippets and output images below:

```
    #calculator

def add(n1,n2):
  """Adds two numbers"""
  return n1 + n2

def subtract(n1,n2):
  """Subtracts two numbers"""
  return n1 - n2

def multiply(n1,n2):
  """Multiplies two numbers"""
  return n1 * n2

def divide(n1,n2):
  """Divides two numbers"""
  return n1 / n2

#we do not add paranthesis because we want to store the names of functions in the dictionary
#we do not want to assign the function and trigger a call for execution itself. Hence only the name of the function will suffice.

operations = {
'+' : add,
'-': subtract,
'*': multiply,
'/': divide,
}

num1 = int(input("What is this first number you want to enter ?\n"))
num2 = int(input("What is this second number you want to enter ?\n"))

for operation_symbols in operations:
  print(operation_symbols)

operation_symbol = input("Pick a symbol from the list above for your calculations")

answer = operations[operation_symbol]
answer(num1,num2)
print(f"{num1} {operation_symbol} {num2} = {answer}")
```

When I write this code: my output is the image below:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSdbf.jpg)

However, when I make the following changes

```
#calculator

def add(n1,n2):
  """Adds two numbers"""
  return n1 + n2

def subtract(n1,n2):
  """Subtracts two numbers"""
  return n1 - n2

def multiply(n1,n2):
  """Multiplies two numbers"""
  return n1 * n2

def divide(n1,n2):
  """Divides two numbers"""
  return n1 / n2

#we do not add paranthesis because we want to store the names of functions in the dictionary
#we do not want to assign the function and trigger a call for execution itself. Hence only the name of the function will suffice.

operations = {
'+' : add,
'-': subtract,
'*': multiply,
'/': divide,
}

num1 = int(input("What is this first number you want to enter ?\n"))
num2 = int(input("What is this second number you want to enter ?\n"))

for operation_symbols in operations:
  print(operation_symbols)

operation_symbol = input("Pick a symbol from the list above for your calculations")

operation_function = operations[operation_symbol]
answer = operation_function(num1,num2)
print(f"{num1} {operation_symbol} {num2} = {answer}")
```

The output I get is the desired one:
[desired output of calculator from above code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsp6O.jpg)

I wanted to know why this happens. I have no idea what is the deal with my code.
Thanks and Regards.

Comment: its because in the first snippet you are never reassigning the `answer` variable, `answer` is holding an reference to a function. You are later calling this function `answer(num1,num2)` but the result isn't assigned to anything.

Comment: Of course, because `answer = operations[operation_symbol]` is *the function object itself*. This isn't weird at all.

Comment: As an aside, you aren't storing the "name of the function", you are *storing the function itself*. A function is just an object, like an `int` or a `str` or a `list`. If you used parentheses, it would *call* the function, and evaluate to whatever the return value is. Doing `answer(num1,num2)` doesn't magically modify the value of `answer`, you'd have to do something liek `answer = answer(num1,num2)`, although, re-using the variable like that would be confusing. Your second approach is reasonable as it is

Comment: Thank you for your succinct explanation. I literally could not find an answer like yours had I not post the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code snippet, you are trying to print the reference to the function itself, rather than the result of the function call, `answer(num1,num2)`. Change it as follows and you will get the desired result:

```
print(f"{num1} {operation_symbol} {num2} = {answer(num1, num2)}")
```

Alternatively,

```
result = answer(num1, num2)
print(f"{num1} {operation_symbol} {num2} = {result}")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first chunk of non-working code, you set:

```
answer = operations[operation_symbol]
```

And in the second chunk, you set:

```
answer = operation_function(num1,num2)
```

So, in the first chunk, you set *answer* to the function itself, and in the second chunk, you set *answer* to the result of applying the func to the two inputs.

What you're seeing is exactly what you should see.  Note that, in the first chunk, you grab and save the function, then on the next line you properly call the function with the two arguments, but you don't save the result.

One way to fix your first chunk would be to change:

```
answer = operations[operation_symbol]
answer(num1,num2)
```

to:

```
answer = operations[operation_symbol](num1,num2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see clearly now what was going on.